# when do I know geth --fast is up to speed?

Tags: go-ethereum

When do I quit geth --syncmode "fast" and run geth --syncmode "full" , how do I know it's done ?

currently running

```
web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
.then(console.log);

web3.eth.isSyncing()
.then(console.log);
```

logs:

```
{ currentBlock: 4402495,
  highestBlock: 4402734,
  knownStates: 14127294,
  pulledStates: 14114278,
  startingBlock: 0 }
0
```

am I done?

Answer (score 0):

You don't switch from one to the other. You run either `--syncmode full` if you want all the transactions on your hard drive, or you run `--syncmode fast` if you want the transactions before the end of time (just kidding).  `--syncmode fast` does not replay and store the entire blockchain. --`--syncmode full` does.

It is not the case that you run in `fast` mode until it's synced and then run in `full` mode as you seem to imply by your question.

Comment: but is'nt --fast pretty useless when I need to interact with the blockchain ? I quit fast and run full till it synced, which was the only way I could read acct balances and events.

Comment: Fast keeps up to the head of the chain, and keeps “some” history but not all the details of all the blocks back to the genesis block. If you want historical balances you can’t use —fast. If you want “recent” balances, you can. I’m not exactly sure where the line between recent and historical is. I seem to remember 250,000 blocks but don’t count on that number.